# Printing content of Variables before a target is called

Tags: makefile

I currently have a makefile that looks like this

```
ifndef __makefile_env_setup_included_1__
export __makefile_env_setup_included_1__ := true

export ENV_ROOT  := $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))/../..)
export ENV_TOOLS := $(ENV_ROOT)/tools

endif   # __makefile_env_setup_included_1__


include $(ENV_TOOLS)/Makefile.utils.function
include $(ENV_TOOLS)/Makefile.utils.variable
include $(ENV_TOOLS)/Makefile.utils.action
include $(ENV_TOOLS)/Makefile.utils.rule
```

I wanted to echo the value of the variables being used like

```
$ENV_ROOT
```

From what I have read so far , I can only insert a command in the commands section of a processed target. My question is is there a way for me to echo out a certain variables before reaching the include file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Functions That Control Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions) to do this. Specifically `$(info)` and `$(warning)`.

> $(warning text…)
>
> This function works similarly to the error function, above, except that make doesn’t exit. Instead, text is expanded and the resulting message is displayed, but processing of the makefile continues.
>
> The result of the expansion of this function is the empty string.
>
> $(info text…)
>
> This function does nothing more than print its (expanded) argument(s) to standard output. No makefile name or line number is added. The result of the expansion of this function is the empty string.